# MacBook Pro 2017 trackpad not working sometimes with dual boot?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, macintosh

This is an interesting problem. I just installed Mint on my MBP 2017 (dual booting, of course), and everything went well. Got the sound working, keyboard works fine, WiFi is good... the only thing that isn’t working consistently is the trackpad. When I reboot the computer, sometimes the trackpad just won’t work at all, no matter what I do. Then, sometimes, it’ll arbitrarily work when I restart the computer (it’s like 1 in 5 times it works). Is there a driver that I’m missing or something? I’ve updated and upgraded everything so that’s out. I’ve looked all over the internet for a solution but found little advice. Can anyone help?

Comment: WRT the trackpad: I get the same thing ***intermittently*** in Ubuntu on my 2011 MBP. I've researched it a bit, but found no cures. In my case, it mostly seems to occur after the machine has sat idle for some time. And BTW, I'm impressed that you were able to get Mint installed on a MBP. I tried this on an older 2011 MBP, and got only frustration for my efforts - tho' Ubuntu installed easily. If you have an install procedure for Mint, I'd love to see it.

Comment: That’s interesting. I followed a procedure for installing Ubuntu and just replaced Ubuntu with mint haha. I followed this video: [https://youtu.be/kRgKlcm1XPI] and this link solves my issue: [https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver]

Comment: I guess that's my problem! :)  Oh, and I wanted to set it up as *dual-boot* macOS/Mint. Did you dual-boot, or just Mint?

Comment: I dual booted. I have to keep macOS for work-related stuff.

Comment: Are you using `rEFInd`?

Comment: Yes, that’s what the video recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The solution:](https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver)

Installs a necessary driver:

```
echo -e "\n# applespi\napplespi\nspi_pxa2xx_platform\nintel_lpss_pci" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

apt install dkms
git clone https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver.git /usr/src/applespi-0.1
dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1
```

Comment: There's a problem with that URL.

Comment: Just remove the %5D from the end. For some reason I can’t edit my answer. SE noob here.

Comment: Probably not your fault... I tried to submit an edit once I saw the problem, but it's in an "approval loop" now  :P  sorry!

Comment: Interesting answer... the README at github says, `The keyboard / trackpad driver here is now included in the kernel as of v5.3.` According to `$ uname -srm`, I've now got:
`Linux 5.4.0-52-generic x86_64`

Comment: Hm, that is interesting. I'm not really sure what to say, unfortunately (not a Linux expert at all). All I know is that I downloaded that driver and my touchpad began working consistently. Perhaps it's a Ubuntu vs Mint issue?

Comment: Could be, what's your kernel version in Mint?

Comment: At any rate it's a useful Q&A I think +2   You should "accept" your answer when you can (SE might have a time delay for *self-answered* Q's).

Answer (score 1):

After the latest update on ubuntu 20.04 LTS, track pad on MBP 2017 stopped working.

The following code helped. I needed to make a directory on `/usr/src` by renaming and moving the `macbook12-spi-driver` folder to `applespi -v 0.1`

This worked on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install dkms
git clone https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver.git /usr/src/applespi-0.1
dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1
```